# How to Generate the Unique Dynamic First Name, Last Name for each Test in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

Here is the situation due to our application complexity and so many Integration env's, we can not delete the Injected Data(through the performance test) before Next test or to repeat the Tests.

Every Time we need to run test about an hour with 10,000 Unique Employee (First Name, Last Name)
Note : First Name & Last Name should be purely alphabetic. Ex: FName: Edward Last Name:Jerick

How do I achieve the above

Comment: Do you mean a random non-sense String or correct unique name? If option 1, then function helper will help.

Comment: Ex: FName: Edward  Last Name: Jerick

Comment: Then you need at least 100 names for each to make 10K unique combination fullname.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it sounds like a functional defect, the system should allow duplicate first and last names combination, I don't know how many John Smiths are in the USA but I suppose that the number is much more than 1.

Whatever.

You can pre-generate the list of 10000 unique first and last names (or at least alphabetic strings) in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the code like:

```
Set<String> firstNames = new HashSet<>()
Set<String> lastNames = new HashSet<>()

0.upto(9999, {
    firstNames.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(16))
})

0.upto(9999, {
    lastNames.add(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(16))
})

0.upto(9999, {
    new File('credentials.csv') << firstNames[it] << ',' << lastNames[it] << System.getProperty('line.separator')
})
```

If you want "real" names instead of random you can check out [Java Faker library](https://www.baeldung.com/java-faker)

Then you can refer the generated data from the `credentials.csv` file in the "normal" Thread Group using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

Comment: It's not functional defect, application looks voter with this combo( First Name, Last Name, DOB,DL,SSN)